# if else problem salary formula for loop desire loop user input

Tags: c++

asking desire number to become the for loop(how many employee if input is 4 then 4 loop if 3 3 loops), salary formula not working, if else statement for string name to not accept number and vice versa integer to not accept letters. another one of my problem is how can I name the loop for example the question is name hours and rate then the cout should do 1. name hours rate, 2.name hours rate 3.name hours rate... the code is working..  just need some imporvements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void displayRules()
{

    cout<<"====================="<<endl;
    cout<<"   EMPLOYEE-SALARY   "<<endl;
    cout<<"====================="<<endl;
    cout<<" "<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    char ans;
    do
    {
system("cls");
displayRules();

    struct Employee
    {
        string name;
        double hours;
        double rate;
        double salary;
        Employee *next;
        Employee *prev;
    };

    Employee *head;
    head=NULL;

    Employee *newEmployee;
    Employee *EmpPointer;
    Employee *nextEmpPointer;
    Employee *prevEmpPointer;

    string inpname;
    int inpN;
    double inphours;
    double inprate;
    double salary;
    salary = (inprate*inphours);


    for(int ctr=0; ctr<3; ctr++)
    {

        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter Name: \t\t";
        cin>> inpname;

        cout<<"Enter # Hours Worked: \t";
        cin>> inphours;

        if (inphours<0)
            {
            cout << "Invalid Input! Program Stopped. ";
            return 0;
            }

        cout<<"Enter Rate per Hour: \t";
        cin>> inprate;

        if (inprate<0)
            {
            cout << "Invalid Input! Program Stopped. ";
            return 0;
            }

        newEmployee = new Employee;
        newEmployee->name=inpname;
        newEmployee->hours=inphours;
        newEmployee->rate=inprate;
        newEmployee->next=NULL;
        if (head==NULL)
            head=newEmployee;
        else
        {
            EmpPointer=head;
            while (EmpPointer->next)
                EmpPointer=EmpPointer->next;
            EmpPointer->next=newEmployee;
        }
    }

    cout<<endl;
    Employee *displayPointer;
    displayPointer=head;

    system("cls");

        cout<<"------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"                    =Summary of PAYROLL=                    "<<endl;
        cout<<"------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;\
        cout<<"Employee Name\t"<<"# Hours Worked\t"<<"Rate/Hour\t"<<"Salary\t"<<endl;

    while (displayPointer)
    {
        cout<<displayPointer->name<<"\t\t";
        cout<<displayPointer->hours<<"\t\t";
        cout<<displayPointer->rate<<"\t\t";
        cout<<displayPointer->salary<<endl;
        displayPointer=displayPointer->next;
    }
    cout<<"------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;

    cout<<endl;
    cout << "Would you like to run the program again? (Y/N) ";
    cin>>ans;
```

}
while (ans == 'y' or ans == 'Y');

return 0;
}

Comment: asking on how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: The salary wasn't being calculated so I fix that.

I broke your code into small functions in which each function only does one thing and one thing only (Single Responsibility Principle).

Also, I introduce function templates that allows you to reuse a function when you provide the type.

Finally, the code is missing a clean up of pointers to prevent memory leaks. Each time you use the keyword `new` to obtain a pointer to memory, you need later to check if the pointer contains `null` and if doesn't then use the keyword `delete` to free that memory, else you end with memory leaks in your code. Therefore, I leave you with the task to write the function that should iterate your employee list and free the memory to prevent memory leaks.

I hope this is useful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct Employee {
    string name;
    double hours;
    double rate;
    double salary;
    Employee *next;
    Employee *prev;
};

void displayRules() {
    cout<<"====================="<<endl;
    cout<<"   EMPLOYEE-SALARY   "<<endl;
    cout<<"====================="<<endl;
    cout<<" "<<endl;
}

// Here we create a function template to make this code more reusable
template <typename T>
T consoleInput(const std::string& prompt) {
    T value;
    std::cout << prompt;
    std::cin >> value;
    return value;
}

// Lets create our own assert to exit the app.
void assertGreaterEqualThanZero(const double value, const std::string& prompt){
    if (value < 0) {
        cout << prompt;
        exit(1);
    }
}

// Small functions that do one thing only makes coding easy to debug
Employee* createEmployee(string name, int hours, int rate) {
    Employee *newEmployee = new Employee;
    newEmployee->name=name;
    newEmployee->hours=hours;
    newEmployee->rate=rate;
    newEmployee->salary = (rate * hours);
    newEmployee->next=NULL;
    // You need to set and maintain ->prev 
    // if you are thinking on using a double linked list
    // else remove it from the structure since is unused.
    return newEmployee;
}

// This is a helper function to add new employees to a list
Employee* addToEmployeeList(Employee* list, Employee* newEmployee){
    if (list==NULL) {
        list = newEmployee;
    } else {
        Employee *EmpPointer = list;
        while (EmpPointer->next)
            EmpPointer=EmpPointer->next;
        EmpPointer->next=newEmployee;
    }
    return list;
}

// The only purpose of this function is to print the list provided
void printEmployeList(Employee* employeeList){
    Employee *currentEmployee = employeeList;
    
    system("cls");

    cout<<"------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"                    =Summary of PAYROLL=                    "<<endl;
    cout<<"------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;

    while (currentEmployee){
        cout<<"Employee Name\t"<<"# Hours Worked\t"<<"Rate/Hour\t"<<"Salary\t"<<endl;
        cout<<currentEmployee->name<<"\t\t";
        cout<<currentEmployee->hours<<"\t\t";
        cout<<currentEmployee->rate<<"\t\t";
        cout<<currentEmployee->salary<<endl;
        cout<<"------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        currentEmployee=currentEmployee->next;
    }
}

// I leave you with this piece that is missing.
// TODO: create function that delete each employee in the list, 
// then deletes the list in order to prevent memory leaks

int main() {
    char ans;
    do {
        system("cls");
        
        displayRules();
    
        Employee *employeeList;
        employeeList=NULL;
    
        for(int ctr=0; ctr<3; ++ctr) {
            
            // Lets declare and instantiate when we need it.
            string name = consoleInput<string>("Enter Name: \t\t");
            
            // No need to use inp (as inphours) in front of your variables
            // It makes it harder to read. Just put hours as a name.
            double hours = consoleInput<double>("Enter # Hours Worked: \t");
            assertGreaterEqualThanZero(hours, "Invalid Input! Program Stopped.");
    
            double rate = consoleInput<double>("Enter Rate per Hour: \t");
            assertGreaterEqualThanZero(rate, "Invalid Input! Program Stopped. ");
    
            Employee *newEmployee = createEmployee(name, hours, rate);
            
            employeeList = addToEmployeeList(employeeList, newEmployee);
        }
    
        cout << endl;
        
        printEmployeList(employeeList);
        
        cout << "Would you like to run the program again? (Y/N) ";
        cin>>ans;
    } while (ans == 'y' or ans == 'Y');
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To whomever voted negative, it would be very constructive if you could leave a note indicating the reason behind the negative vote. Since the user requested to show how could the code could be improved. Thank you.